# Hermite interpolation and basis functions.

Tags: reference-request, interpolation, reference-works, hermite-polynomials

I am using piecewise quintic Hermite interpolation at the joint level for a robot (1000 Hz) from a more time-sparse, but smooth trajectory (100 Hz). I have tested this according to the elegant mathematics in some lecture notes by Professor D.L. Finn[1].

It works nicely, and I wish to document it, but I can not find any bibliographic reference to the "basis functions"; $H_i^n$ for spline order $n$ in the lecture notes. What are they called, and where do I find something published on Hermite interpolation using these basis functions?

Example for the cubic case, from the lecture notes:

$$\begin{align}
H_0^3(t) &= 1 - 3t^2 + 2t^3 \\
H_1^3(t) &= t - 2t^2 + t^3 \\
H_2^3(t) &= -t^2 + t^3 \\
H_3^3(t) &= 3t^2 - 2t^3 
\end{align}$$

I have sent professor Finn the same question, and will post here if I get some information from him.

[1] D.L. Finn, "MA 323 Geometric Modelling, Course Notes: Day 09, Quintic Hermite Interpolation", 2004, \url{https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~finn/CCLI/Notes/day09.pdf}

Comment: I don't know what name they could have, but they are quite easy to derive for arbitrary order of smoothness with a big equation system if you want to do that.

Comment: Here is an idea for a possibly more general version if it would be of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525868/polynomic-curve-interpolation-with-tensor-differential-constraints

Comment: @mathreadler, thanks for the comments, and the interesting formulation in your new post. I know they fairly easy to derive, but the short (engineering)paper I am trying to write, I think I would not be allowed the space to do so. I would need to reference some scientific literature instead.

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't know so many literature sources, I am afraid. But it is a good question, there is a fair chance someone else on this site has seen them in some context. Maybe you can e-mail and ask the course owner of the lecture notes for sources. I added the tags "reference works" and "reference request" which can be good when asking for references to literature.

Comment: @mathreadler, I did write him simultaneous to posting here. I have put this information in my post now. I will update my post, if he responds. Very good of you to add those tags!

Comment: I can derive it in terms of matrices if you want. But maybe it is overkill?

Comment: No, I think a reference to the lecture note will be better than deriving it in the paper. I am able to derive it myself, but I am fairly certain that it will not be accepted in a publication.

Comment: Aha so it needs to pass for publication. Well, good luck.