# Polynomic curve interpolation with tensor differential constraints?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, soft-question, interpolation, least-squares

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525696/hermite-interpolation-and-basis-functions#comment7251274_3525696) and [these lecture notes](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~finn/CCLI/Notes/day09.pdf)  which belong to it, where derivatives of specific points is prescribed to be some known vectors.

Let us consider the $${\bf c}'(0) = {\bf v_0}\\{\bf c}'(1) = {\bf v_1}$$

equations, and say that we don't know $\bf v_0$ or $\bf v_1$, but that we want to punish certain orientations.

$${\bf T_0} {\bf c}'(0) - {\bf d_0}={\bf 0}\\{\bf T_1} {\bf c}'(1) - {\bf d_1}={\bf 0}$$
Or maybe (which would be a softer version) to do least squares fit :
$$\|{\bf c}(0)-{\bf p_0}\|_2+\|{\bf c}(1)-{\bf p_1}\|_2+\|{\bf T_0} {\bf c}'(0) - {\bf d_0}\|_2+\|{\bf T_1}{\bf c}'(1) - {\bf d_1}\|_2$$

Where $\bf T_0,T_1$ are two known tensors and $\bf d_0, d_1$ are two known vectors.

Just to show the power of the approach, we could imagine $$\begin{cases}{\bf T_0 = I - \hat v_0}{\bf \hat v_0}^T\\{\bf T_1 = I - \hat v_1}{\bf \hat v_1}^T\\\bf d_0=0\\\bf d_1=0\end{cases}$$

Which would allow **any vectors in the same orientation** as $\bf v_0$ and $\bf v_1$, respectively, but with unknown magnitudes.

We will also realize that the special case $$\begin{cases}\bf T_0= I\\\bf T_1 = I\\\bf d_0=v_0\\ \bf d_1=v_1\end{cases}$$
would take us back to the original formulation.

How would solving this problem differ from solving the original formulation?

Or rephrased: Is there some framework of solving the original question which would be rich enough to allow us to add cost terms, like the one above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach does not work. There is at least one particular reason for this.

Consider ${\bf c}'(1) = [\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2]^T$

Our optimization can pick any $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ arbitrarily close to 0, and we can get any orientation of the tangent vector.

What we would like to express in this case is something like $$\frac{{\bf c}'(1)}{|{\bf c}'(1)|}$$
And then multiply with tensors. But this is very non-linear. It will not fit into our linear algebra framework.

I would think we could do better to do an approach with integral of polar coordinates or some such thing.